# Are my Hi-Speed numbers adequate for Voip?

Tags: speed, voip, bandwidth, broadband

When I test my broadband speed I get these numbers returned:
Download - 8.1 Mb/s ::
Upload - .511 Mb/s ::

Are these numbers high enough to support a voip application?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is plenty of bandwidth.

As a reference:

- Skype uses [between 3-16KB/sec during VoIP calls.](https://support.skype.com/faq/FA151/How-much-bandwidth-does-Skype-use-while-I-m-in-a-call)
- Ventrilo, depending on the codec of the server, [uses around 3KB/sec per person talking](http://www.ventrilo.com/setup.php#Client_Network_Requirements) (download) and likely 3KB/sec while you talk (upload)

We have similar speeds as you at my work, and have no issues with VoIP with 2 people online.

Answer (score 1):

I would be more worried about latency and the actual VOIP provider you are using.

However, I use VOIP to chat to my father when he is abroad and whilst crackly, we can talk fine when he is on 2Mb down, 128 Up, so on your speeds should be more than adequate.

Comment: +1 for latency.

My latency is about 25ms.
Good? Bad?

Thanks

Comment: 25 should be excellent... Really, anything under 60 is probably good enough for clear voip

Answer (score 0):

If its just one user, and you're not going to be doing a lot of web intensive stuff at the same time, sure.

Obviously it's the upload bandwidth that's your bottleneck, but VOIP tends to only use around 90kbps, though iirc you can drop it to 60 or even 30 (though each comes with a notable drop in sound quality).

Answer (score 0):

The minimum bandwidth required depends on the VOIP codec used. [Here](http://voip.about.com/od/voipbasics/a/voipcodecs.htm) is a list of commonly used codecs and as you can see 512 kbps is more than enough. It could be a problem only if you intend to have multiple concurrent connections.

Comment: Consider fixing spelling.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few good online VoIP tools that will check your speed and tell you how you will perform.  One is [myspeed.visualware.com/voip](http://myspeed.visualware.com/voip/).  You can google voip speed tests to find others.